# Is it ok if I share config data with all components from a js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have config data, it will affect every component's status at the same time.

So, I import that config object from the same js file, and use it in the component's data.

Seems to be good, if I change the config from its origin, all components will change their view dynamically.

But, I can't find this way in any other projects, which does not seem regular.

If I keep doing this, will any problems occur?

Config data:

```
export default {
  status: {
    name: 'xxx',
    sex: 'male'
  }
}
```

All components:

```
import config from './config'

data() {
  return {
    config
  }
}
```

If I fire this method from any one of these components, all components would change:

```
methods: {
  setUser() {
    this.config.state.name = 'yyy'
  }
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What about using globals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It differs as per project requirement. However, looking at your requirement, you need to access the data in every component rather than in some components. In this case, you may configure a middleware which will invoked in all components.

Using middleware will serve you benefit not to import the config in every components.

If you want to invoke them in some components only then you may configure [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) or [plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html).

And providing answer for this seems to be a broad post. I hope you'd find useful resources to learn and use them. However, here's a good read which will explain when to use component, mixins, and plugins:

[component vs mixins vs plugins](https://medium.com/@victorlucss/component-vs-mixins-vs-plugins-in-vue-js-6a8bce29d6ec)

Comment: > And providing answer for this seems to be a broad post.

Sorry, I tried. maybe my words are not precise, can not find the answer ;(

Comment: @TsuyiRen Yes, I meant for providing answer for all concepts middleware, mixins, plugins and components. However, I have linked few which you should start reading first.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any problem to use this way. But you could use vuex for state management and follow the redux pattern. .